# What is Difference between Managed Object and Object Type in KMIP?

Tags: protocol-analysis

I currently study and develop the KMIP.

I test the [sample](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benutzer:MeileGuster/Key_Management_Interoperability_Protocol)(Part of sample message encode(Beispiel Nachricht Enkodierung)) with opensource, [KMIP4J](https://sourceforge.net/projects/kmip4j/). I think Symmetric Key(Object Type) in sample is Managed Object. and I also think Managed Object shall be contain the Key Block Structure as [KMIP document](http://docs.oasis-open.org/kmip/spec/v1.0/os/kmip-spec-1.0-os.html)(2.2.2 Symmetric Key). but sample has not Key Block, Instead of containing Template Attribute(Cryptographic Algorithm, Cryptographic Length and Cryptographic Usage Mask). 
however, [KMIP document](http://docs.oasis-open.org/kmip/spec/v1.0/os/kmip-spec-1.0-os.html)(4.1 Create) explain using create operation.

1. What is Difference between Managed Object and Object Type in KMIP?

thanks.. I wish to help, anyone who's reply will be very helpful!.